Can't change text decoration color anymore in flutter
I have the following text widget
Text(
  todo.todoText!,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    color: (isDark) ? Colors.white : Colors.black87,
    decoration: todo.isDone ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
    decorationColor: (isDark) ? Colors.white : Colors.black87  // error
)

This is the error I get:

The named parameter 'decorationColor' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'decorationColor'

As far as the official docs goes

There is indeed a named parameter called decorationColor.
I'm using Flutter 3.16.9
Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 41456452f2 (4 months ago) • 2024-01-25 10:06:23 -0800
Engine • revision f40e976bed
Tools • Dart 3.2.6 • DevTools 2.28.5

Please help me out :)

Can you share your desired result or more information about question?

it's probably because your IDE analysis isn't finished yet

It seems like you have closed the TextStyle bracket before decorationColor line.

@NipulRathod I want to change the color of the line-through text decoration but I get an error when I try to do so

@AnteBule So silly of me :) thanks btw. Should I delete the question?

@SaptarshiDey Np ;). I think you should delete it, but it's your decision after all.

Yes, it's a syntax error:
You have closed the Parantheses-bracket of TextStyle object while giving more parameters like decorationColor.
decoration: todo.isDone ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),

To
decoration: todo.isDone ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,

